# How do i click this specific nav button with Selenium webdriver

Tags: python, selenium

Here is a copy/paste from the source

```
<li id="find-tab" data-qa="sidebar.find.tab" class="nav-tab active">
<span class="in"></span>
<p id="find-label">FIND</p></li>
```

I have tried:

```
driver.find_element_by_link_text("FIND").click()
```

and:

```
driver.find_element_by_css_se("nav-tab").click()
```

neither is working.

How do I just simply click on the nav button given that source code I pasted above?

Comment: `driver.find_element_by_id('find-label').click()` or `WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(expected_conditions.element_to_be_clickable((By.ID, 'find-label'))).click()`

Comment: if you can change the <p> to an <a> that would make your by_link_text work. The nav-tab class might not work if there are multiple matches. Try a selector that will be unique to the element - maybe by_id "find-label"

Answer (score 0):

As suggested by @Random Davis in the comments as well. You can use :

```
driver.find_element_by_id('find-label').click();
```

**Note** : Please make sure this would work appropriately for the cases when the *find-label* element is unique in the page source.

In case there are chances of them being in multiple places, you can create and use a list using :

```
findLink = driver.find_elements_by_id('find-label');
for links in findLink:
    print links.click();
    # do whatever you want and navigate back to access the next find-label element
```